# Cosmos DB error "StartIndex cannot be less than zero" when adding to Entity Collection

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to add to an entity collection using Entity Framework Core Cosmos DB.

This code:

```
_repository.Accounts.Add(account)
```

Throws this exception:

> StartIndex cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'startIndex')

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

EF Core Cosmos DB doesn't evaluate the JsonProperty attribute.

So, I had to change this:

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
public string Identifier { get; set; }
```

To this:

```
private string id { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public string Identifier
{
   get => id;
   set => id = value;
}
```

All good now.